# Importing September 2011 data dump into MS SQL

Tags: support, data-dump

I am trying to import the September 2011 data dump into MS SQL using [Stack Overflow Data Dump Import](https://github.com/peschkaj/soddi/releases/tag/v1.0). I am a novice with SQL server projects and would really appreciate your help and suggestions to get around with this.

After creating an empty SQL server project named Database1 in Visual Studio, I typed the following in the application's GUI:

```
Source:
C:\OSU\092011 Photography
```

Where `092011 Photography` is the folder containing the XML data of https://photo.stackexchange.com/.

```
Target:
Data Source="C:\Users\Nira\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects";Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=True
```

I am not sure what these values are supposed to be...

```
Provider:
System.Data.SqlClient
```

I don't think I ever configured MS SQL server, so I'd probably have to do that.

Comment: This isn't really [on-topic for Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/help/on-topic).  This kind of question belongs more on [so].

Comment: I thought my question is very similar to this :http://stackapps.com/questions/2511/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-for-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-and#69956                        Thats why I posted it here.

Comment: That is not a question, it is an App announcement for a tool developed by the OP.  That's completely different from a programming question like this one.  On StackApps, many questions are not questions at all, they are tool announcements -- which is the only purpose allowed here for the `app`, `script`, and `library` tags.